# Always yield a masked array with netCDF4

Tags: python, numpy, netcdf, masked-array

**Question:**

Is there a way of forcing `netCDF4` to *always* output a masked array, regardless of whether it slice contains any fill values?

**Background:**

I have a netCDF dataset of values on a grid, over time that I read using the `netCDF4` package.

`nc_data = netCDF4.Dataset('file.nc', 'r')`

The initial timesteps yield masked arrays:

```
var1_t0 = nc_data.variables['var1'][0][:]
var1_t0
masked_array(...)
```

The later timesteps yield standard `ndarrays`:

```
var1_t200 = nc_data.variables['var1'][200][:]
var1_t200
ndarray(...)
```

**Desired result:**

I would like masked arrays for the latter with a mask of all `False`, rather than a standard ndarray.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think this is directly possible, but you can work it around by creating a `masked_array` if necessary:

```
var1_t0 = nc_data.variables['var1'][0][:]
if type(var1_t0) is numpy.ma.core.MaskedArray:
    var1_t0 = numpy.ma.core.MaskedArray(var1_t0, numpy.zeros(var1_t0.shape, dtype = bool))
```